# How to update json with user input list in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I m writing command line script in python to execute my scala code. but I m struct in formating the input json with List.

see below some part of python script:

```
CONTEXT_SETTINGS = """
    {
    "CustomerTable": {
        "table": "%s",
        "host" : "localhost",
    "customerList" : %s
        }
    }
    """
class CmdLineParser():
    def __init__(self, description):
        self.parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description=description)

    self.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', default=False,
                      action='store_true',
                      help='Verbose mode')   
    self.add_argument('-t', '--table', nargs='?',
                     help='my table', required=True)

    def add_argument(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parser.add_argument(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_ctx_config(self, cust_sub_ids):
        args = self.parser.parse_args()

        context_dict = json.loads(
            CONTEXT_SETTINGS % (args.table, customerids))
        return context_dict
```

how to load json file to set the customerids.
where customerids = ['1234', '2345', '5678' .....] and get_ctx_config is call from main file.

so that input json file should become

```
{
"CustomerTable": {
    "table": "mytable",
    "host" : "localhost",
    "customerList" : ["1234", 2345", "5678"]          
  }
}
```

and context_dic return should like:

```
 u'CustomerTable': {u'table': u'mytable', u'host': u'localhost', u'cust_sub_id': [u'1234', u'1235', u'1236', u'1237', u'1234']}
```

how to write python script to update the.

```
 context_dict = json.loads(
         CONTEXT_SETTINGS % (args.table, customerids))
```

and what will be needed to set type for list in CONTEXT_SETTING like %s for String.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why are you storing your data structure in a string to begin with? Why not just have CONTEXT_SETTINGS be a dictionary

Answer (score 3):

Why use JSON when all you want is a dictionary?

```
context_dict = {
"CustomerTable": {
    "table": args.table,
    "host" : "localhost",
    "customerList" : customerids          
  }
}
```

Comment: only for understanding. for e.g. it should look like.